# window keypress listener also called on textbox keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in jquery and javascript. I have a page which has window.keypress event register and a textbox which also has keypress event. on pressing key in textbox both events are called. 1 from textbox keypress and then 2 from window.press. i have tried preventDefault, stopPropagation, stopImmediatePropagation. I want only textbox keypress should be called not the global window.keypress when textbox has focus.
Can you please guide me how i can prevent window.keypress not to be called.

Code

```js
function myFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var text = $('#close').val();
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    if (text.toUpperCase() === "CLOSE") {
      console.log("Closed");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example that didn't work for you using `evt.preventDefault()`? That would go a long way to helping readers understand the issue.

Comment: function myFunction(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var text=$('#close').val();
    if(e.keyCode === 13){
        if(text.toUpperCase()==="CLOSE"){
            console.log("Closed");
        }
    }
}$(window).keypress(function (e) {
        
        console.log("Window keypress");
    });

Comment: Better to edit your post and include your code in a formatted fashion. I copied your code and tried to prettify it on my end, but it didn't work.

Comment: `stopPropagation` in the textbox event handler should do what you want.

Comment: Is the code you posted for the window listener or the textbox listener?

Comment: I added you comment to the question. Please show how you register the event handler

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: yes stopPropagation helps now. I was having some errors in html code. Thanks for your help

Comment: **Never use stopPropagation()** (Unless you really, really know what you're doing). There's not a single valid reason to limit other layers of your application or third parties  knowing an event happened.

Comment: code is for textbox